Change default Series 1 for a changing name
I have a column chart and I want to modify the name that is inside the column. The problem is that I do not want a static name neither the default one (Series 1)
The code is the following:
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      CCAA = c(
        "ANDALUCÍA",
        "CEUTA",
        "COMUNITAT VALENCIANA",
        "CASTILLA-LA MANCHA",
        "EXTREMADURA",
        "CASTILLA Y LEÓN"
      ),
      TOTAL = c(27,
                14, 4, 2, 2, 1),
      COLOR = c(
        "#E30613",
        "#E30614",
        "#E30615",
        "#E30616",
        "#E30617",
        "#E30618"
      ),
      BANDERAS = c(
        "FLAG 1",
        "FLAG 2",
        "FLAG 3",
        "FLAG 4",
        "FLAG 5",
        "FLAG 6"
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L)
  )

And the code of the highcharter plot is:
grafico <- highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = 'column') %>%
    hc_tooltip(table=TRUE) %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$BANDERAS) %>%
    hc_colors(color=df$COLOR) %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
    hc_legend(enabled=FALSE) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(series = list(animation = FALSE)) %>% 
    hc_add_series(df$TOTAL, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='<span style="fontfamily: sans-serif">{point.y}</span>'), colorByPoint=TRUE)

How can I do to put at Series 1, the name of the CCAA instead of the default one, and at the x axis the different names of BANDERA?

You can customize the tooltip using hc_tooltip and a custom JS formatter function:
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(
    type = "column"
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(table = TRUE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$BANDERAS) %>%
  hc_colors(color = df$COLOR) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      animation = FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = df[c("TOTAL", "CCAA")] |> dplyr::rename(y = TOTAL),
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = TRUE,
      format = '<span style="fontfamily: sans-serif">{point.y}</span>'
    ),
    colorByPoint = TRUE
  ) |>
  hc_tooltip(
    formatter = JS(
      "
      function () {
        return '<b>' + this.points[0].point.CCAA + '</b>:' + this.y;
      }
      "
    )
  )



First of all, really thank you but I do not want that. I want that instead CCAA, I want to put the name of that CCAA, in the image it will be ANDALUCÍA: 27. How can I do it?

Thanks, it works extremly well. But I have still one problem. I want to put at the xAxis the column BANDERA (see new df). But the name of the hc_tooltip I want to remain the previous one (the CCAA name) and with the previous code, CCAA does not appear. Take a look at the new df I put

See my updated answer. To achieve that you have to pass the CCAA column to the data argument too and rename the column you want to display as bars.

Thanks Stefan, it is exactly what I wanted
